# R check dataframe contains the necessary combinations across 3 columns

Tags: r, dataframe, row, combinations

I have a large df in R that contains a list of countries, years and scenarios. I need to check that the df contains all necessary combinations of those three variables according to a pre-specified list. See example:

Pre-defined list:

```
country_list = c("AFG", "BWA", "CIV")
year_list = c(2020, 2021, 2022)
scenario_list = c("Const", "Decr", "Incr")
```

Dataframe:

```
ISO3 = c("AFG", "AFG","AFG","AFG", "AFG","AFG","AFG", "AFG","AFG","BWA", "BWA","BWA","BWA", "BWA","BWA","BWA", "BWA","BWA","CIV","CIV","CIV","CIV","CIV","CIV","CIV","CIV","CIV")

Year = c(2020, 2021, 2022, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2020, 2021, 2023, 2020, 2021, 2023, 2020, 2021, 2023)

Scenario = c("Const", "Const","Const","Decr", "Decr","Decr","Incr","Incr","Incr","Const", "Const","Const","Decr", "Decr","Decr","Incr","Incr","Incr","Const", "Const","Const","Decr", "Decr","Decr","Incr","Incr","Incr")

df = data.frame (ISO3, Year, Scenario)
```

The first rows of the resulting df look like this:

| ISO3 | Year | Scenario |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AFG | 2020 | Const |
| AFG | 2021 | Const |
| AFG | 2022 | Const |
| AFG | 2020 | Decr |
| AFG | 2021 | Decr |
| AFG | 2022 | Decr |

I would like a piece of code that outputs the missing row combingations. In this case, CIV does not have Scenarios for the year 2022, only for 2020, 2021 and 2023.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tidyr::complete` to augment the data frame with any missing combinations of ISO3/Year. Any that are added will be missing a `Scenario` value, so we can filter to just see those.

```
library(tidyverse)
df |>
  complete(ISO3, Year) |>
  filter(is.na(Scenario))

# A tibble: 3 × 3
  ISO3   Year Scenario
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>   
1 AFG    2023 NA      
2 BWA    2023 NA      
3 CIV    2022 NA
```